# How can I make my bundle display name appear different in Settings and under my icon? (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

I have a long title for my app that looks nice in Settings, but doesn't fit under my app icon. Is there a way to have a different Bundle Display Name for under my icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: NO

The difference between CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName is that CFBundleDisplayName is localizable.

App title, notifications and settings all read from CFBundleDisplayName

See techninal details here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1892/_index.html